# Azure cloud shell error

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I am unable to do anything with my Azure account such as create servers or databases or anything.  It seems like it all revolves around resource groups which I cannot create> I get this error:

[image: Resource Group add error]

It's especially tough because I can't even use a cloud shell since I get this:
Requesting a Cloud Shell.
PowerShell may take up to a minute.Failed to provision a Cloud Shell: {"code":"AuthenticationFailed","message":"Authentication failed. The 'Authoriza
tion' header is missing."}

Any idea what this could mean?

Comment: restart you browser in incognito mode and see if that helps

Comment: incognito mode did not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a valid subscription?
If you do make sure you have the right permissions to it.

Cloud shell need to create a storage to work.  If you can't create any resource on subscription cloud shell will surely fail.

Comment: I started my account with a Free Trial.  I have a full MSDN subscription so when the Trial expired was when this started.  I hadn't thought about that.  I have credits on my account so I should still be able to use my MSDN right?

Comment: Did you start a new subscription or just removed limits on the Trial subscription?

Comment: I started a Free Trial, then I added my MSDN subscription.  I removed my free trial because I knew it would expire in 30 days anyway.  Now I can't do anything.  I'm sure I did this to myself.  Can I completely delete my Azure account and add it back?

Comment: If you delete the account you might not be able to use you MSDN Subscription again.

In you Azure Portal, when you login, under subscription do you see both subscriptions?

From your explanation you might just have a disable subscription and the MSDN is not activated.

Comment: I removed my msdn subscription and added it back in so the only active one I have is my msdn.  I still get the same error.  My trial license is totally gone at this point now 2 months later but I continue to get the same error.